# AsyncTask cannot work in thread android

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-asynctask

I use AsyncTask to change text of TextView like this:

```
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            response += url;
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Everything will fine if I call it in OnClick event:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    Button button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          new LongOperation().execute(new String[]{"Hello"});
        }
      });
   }
```

But the problem when I called it in my thread, the program forced close

```
this.closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Thread t= new Thread(){               
           @Override
             public void run(){                                     
              try{
                    //Do something
                    //Then call AsyncTask
                new LongOperation().execute(new String[]{"Hello"});

               }catch(Exception e){}
         }
        };      
         t.start();
        }
      });
```

Where am I wrong? I dont' understand how difference call AsyncTask in thread or not.

Comment: I am curious why you would need to call AsyncTask in another Thread as by itself AsyncTask is a separate Thread already. It seems that the comment // Do something that you put in another Thread could be part of the doInBackground in LongOperation. You might have a valid use case but I have rarely seen such use of Thread within Thread such as what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend you consult the [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) for a better understanding of how it works. Essentially, you should create your [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) subclass on the main thread.

When you call [AsyncTask.execute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29), your provided, [AsyncTask.onPreExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) is called on the main thread, so you can do UI setup.

Next [AsyncTask.doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) method is called, and runs in its own thread.

Finally, when your [AsyncTask.doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) method completes, a call is made to [AsyncTask.onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) on the main thread, and you can do any UI cleanup.

If you need to update the UI from within your [AsyncTask.doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) method, call [AsyncTask.publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29), which will invoke [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks, I have read document and examples. I knew how it work. I found this rule:The task instance must be created on the UI thread. But I want to call it in my own thread. How can I do that?

Comment: Async Task by itself is a therad,so u dont need to put in thread

Answer (score 2):

When you call it from the UI thread, the associated `Context` is the running `Activity`. When you call it from a regular thread, there is no valid `Context` associated with that thread. `AsyncTask` executes in its own thread, you shouldn't be creating its own thread. If that is actual code, then you have missunderstood the point of `AsyncTask`. Search for tutorials on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I have read document and some tutorials, I knew how to use it. But the problem is that I **must** use thread and do something. After that, the UI should be update. However I cannot find the way to try that.

Comment: If you must create a thread outside of the main UI thread, then AsyncTask is the wrong way to go. You can still create normal threads, and make calls between them using [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) and [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what the others have said: I think you can use AsyncTask to launch off a task in another thread, even if you start the AsyncTask from a different thread than the UI already.

But in that case, the only way you'll only be able to modify the UI indirectly, for example: pass the handler of the current Activity somehow to this AsyncTask instance, and send messages to it (handler messages get processed on the UI thread). Or use broadcast intents that the Activity catches and updates the UI accordingly, etc. These solutions seem to be overkills though.