# How to execute AsyncTask in endless loop?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have AsyncTask class with methods like this(class: `ApiConnector`):

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids)
{ 
    return getToken(); //<-- do many the most important things and return String
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

and then in my Activity:

```
new ApiConnector()
{
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        Log.d("here: ", result);
    }
}.execute();
```

It work's fine when I execute this one time, but i have to do this in endless loop to take always fresh token like fresh apples in my market. I tried something like that:

```
while (true)
{
    new ApiConnector()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            Log.d("here!", result);
        }
    }.execute();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

and many many stupid things, but i can't find working way. All thread bussiness is tricky for me. Give me some kick and I manage this for sure.

Comment: to call async in loop? Thats a very bad decision dude. use a `Timer` or `Handler` to update your token or whatever in a given period of time. you can also `callOnExecutor()` AsyncTask to run multiple threads parallely

Comment: I write something in android for the very first time so very bad decision is normal for me. Thank for help, i will read more about Timer or Handler.

Answer (score 0):

Like *hrskrs* commented I would prefer using a `Handler` to execute something repeatedly. The main advantage is that `postDelayed` makes the `run()` method  execute in the main application thread - so you can access and change UI components.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyTest implements Runnable {
    private final static int INTERVAL = 5000;

    private Handler mHandler;

    private MyTest() {
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    public void start() {
        run();
    }

    public void stop() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // put here the logic that you want to be executed
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this.  All AsyncTasks run on one thread.  If you infinitely loop inside an AsyncTask, you'll starve all other tasks.  If you have each task start a new task, then you'll still risk major starvation issues.

If you want to do this (and I'm not sure you really do, but lets ignore that), the correct way is to use a Thread.  A Thread can just have a giant while(true) loop and a sleep statement at the end.

Comment: Use a Thread is a problem, for example:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857343/asynctask-cannot-work-in-thread-android

I didnt write it but getToken() is only a stupid name - in real life i need to do there a lot of things like download json and sth else (its not important right now). Simple solution like write method downloadJson didnt work, because i cant do stuff like that in android main thread activity. I get "correct way" to do this in AsyncTask (better dont change), but i want refresh my json for 30 seconds and now i get problem - how to do that with that strange AsyncTask.

Comment: First off, thaat question was written by someone who didn't understand what they were doing-  an asynctask can be called from a thread just fine.  Secondly, you'd be using a Thread *instead of* an AsyncTask.  An AsyncTask is the wrong solution for what you want.